# Edit and submit image in c# doesn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I added upload image field and store both in database(save path) and hard drive(images).

When i edit the image field and submit, it didn't submit instead it shows "upload your image" in alert.

So i think i need to check whether images include in hard drive or image path in database.

I'm not able to do this, because i'm fresher in .net.

Here is my code;

```
     <tr>
            <td>
            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Image"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ControlStyle-Width="50" ControlStyle-Height = "50"  />

        </td>
        <td>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fileupload" runat="server" />  
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="btnsub" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnsub_Click" OnClientClick="return register();" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnrst" runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClick="btnrst_Click" />
        </td>
</tr>
```

cs:

```
protected void btnsub_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();
            if (Textid.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure3", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Textid.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Textusername.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Textclass.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Textsection.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Textaddress.Text.Trim());
                try
                {
                    string filename = string.Empty;
                    if (fileupload.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
                    {
                        filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName);
                        fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename));
                    }                    
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image",(filename.Length>0)? "Images/" + filename:string.Empty);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    btnsub.Text = ex.Message;
                }
                Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure1", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Textusername.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Class", Textclass.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Section", Textsection.Text.Trim());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Textaddress.Text.Trim());
                try
                {
                    string filename = string.Empty;
                    if (fileupload.PostedFile.FileName.Length > 0)
                    {
                        filename = Path.GetFileName(fileupload.PostedFile.FileName);
                        fileupload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/" + filename));
                    }
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image",(filename.Length>0)? "Images/" + filename:string.Empty);
                    com.ExecuteNonQuery();                    
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    btnsub.Text = ex.Message;
                }
                Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx");
            }
        }
        protected void btnrst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Textid.Text = string.Empty;
            Textusername.Text = string.Empty;
            Textclass.Text = string.Empty;
            Textsection.Text = string.Empty;
            Textaddress.Text = string.Empty;
            Image1.ImageUrl = string.Empty;
        }
        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = Connection.DBconnection();

            if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
            {            
                GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)((Button)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
                int index = gr.RowIndex; 
                hiddenfield.Value = index.ToString(); 
                Textid.Text = gr.Cells[0].Text;
                Textusername.Text = gr.Cells[1].Text;
                Textclass.Text = gr.Cells[2].Text;
                Textsection.Text = gr.Cells[3].Text;
                Textaddress.Text = gr.Cells[4].Text;                
                Image1.ImageUrl = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image)gr.Cells[5].Controls[0]).ImageUrl;                    

            }
            else if (e.CommandName == "Deleterow")
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("StoredProcedure4", con);
                com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument));
                var id = Int32.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());                
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Redirect("studententry.aspx");
            }
        }
        protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = GridView1.SelectedIndex;
            hiddenfield.Value = index.ToString();
        }
```

validation:

```
function register() {if (document.getElementById("<%=fileupload.ClientID%>").value == "") {
            alert("Upload Your image !");
            document.getElementById("<%=fileupload.ClientID%>").focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In file upload control, you are getting file path, not file. So it is firing validation for file. If you don't want to change image for that record then disable validation on edit, or you can upload fresh new file.

Your validation code should be

```
           function register() {
             if (document.getElementById("<%=hiddenfield.ClientID%>").value == "") { 
                if (document.getElementById("<%=fileupload.ClientID%>").value == "") { 
                alert("Upload Your image !"); 
                document.getElementById("<%=fileupload.ClientID%>").focus(); return false; 
                }
             }         
          }
```

Comment: if i disable validation.. then when i insert fresh details, the image field will be empty right?

Comment: please paste in quetion and format. It's quite cluttered

Comment: can you please check?

Comment: may i know,, what is hoddenfield?

Comment: sorry, it's hiddenfield, typo err

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95297/discussion-between-rani-and-imad).